# Play2 - Merging two JsResult objects

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I would like to know if it is possible to merge JsResult objects, something similar to ~> operator in play 2.1+. In the following code I want to validate two inputs and then update user information accordingly.

The **and** operator below between two validate method calls is not valid. Is there a way in play to combine two JsResult objects together in the following scenario ?

```
def update(uid:String) =  Action { request=>
  ( JsString(uid).validate[BSONObjectID] **and** request.body.validate[User]) match {
    case JsSuccess(user,_) =>  Async {
      collection.update(Json.obj("_id"->uid),v).map{
        case someError:LastError if someError.err.isDefined =>  ....
        case noError => ...
      }
    }
    case errors:JsError => Ok(JsError.toFlatJson(errors))
  }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use flatmap to combine the JsResults.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can join two JsResult into one:

```scala
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._

def update(uid:String) =  Action { request =>
  (JsString(uid).validate[BSONObjectID] and request.body.validate[User]).tupled 
    match {
      case JsSuccess((uid,user),_) =>  Async {
```

`tupled` and `and` is part of the `play.api.libs.functional` package.